# Why is my POST with cURL not returning JSON correctly?

Tags: php, json, post, curl, docusignapi

In PHP, I'm trying to retrieve the url for a specific page in DocuSign that constantly refreshes. The POST to retrieve this url is in the form:

```
POST http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

This should return a json file in the form:

```
{
  "url": "example.example.com"
}
```

However, I am extremely new to using PHP and POST methods and don't believe I'm doing this correctly. The API explorer for this method in particular is [here](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeViews&operations=createRecipient&mode=basic). I am using cURL methods to make this request. Here is my code (`$recipient`,`$account_id`,`$access_token` are found accurately within another file):

```
$url = "http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/$account_id
         /envelopes/$envelope_id/views/recipient";

$body = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
              "authenticationMethod" => "None",
              "email" => "$recipient",
              "userName" => "$recipient");

$body_string = json_encode($body);

$header = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body_string),
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_string);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

var_dump($response);
```

I am able to get the correct return on the API explorer, but not when making the request with PHP. I believe this is due to the fact that I am not incorporating the `$header` or `$body` correctly, but at this point I am just not sure.

**ADDED:** This is the raw output for the request when correctly running the method on the API Explorer:

Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com
Referer: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5)
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer fGehcK7fkRvFguyu/7NGh01UUFs=
Content-Length:
Content-Type: application/json

This is the JSON request being formed in my code:

```
{
  "returnUrl":"http:\/\/www.docusign.com\/devcenter",
  "authenticationMethod":"Password",
  "email":"example@example.com",
  "userName":"example@example.com",
  "clientUserId":"4c6228f4-fcfe-47f9-bee1-c9d5e6ab6a41",
  "userId":"example@example.com"
}
```

Comment: don't use print_r for debugging. use `var_dump()`. if curl_exec or json_decode fail, they'll return a boolean false, which print_r displays as a zero-length string. var_dump will properly show `(bool)false`

Comment: When I use `var_dump($response)` I get NULL

Comment: See the answer I just posted...

Comment: Either way with apiVersion in or removed (but it needs to be in) I get NULL

Comment: could u add accountID and envelopId for testing the API ? so we can try something out

Comment: Unfortunately not because it is sensitive information. The accountID belongs to the client and the envelopeId is the document that the client sent to the customer to be signed.

Comment: create $body as array,after send json_ncode($body ) with CURL,

Comment: Please post the raw request this is generating and post here (you can redact any sensitive info).  You can do this by logging into your sandbox and going to Preferences -> Privacy Settings then enable REQUEST LOGGING.  Then make the call through code and go retrieve the log it creates.

Comment: Okay I will do that right now

Comment: We need the actual JSON request that your code generates, you've only posted the headers so far.  Can you post the JSON body as well?

Comment: Yes updating the question right now

Comment: Ok but we need the outgoing JSON request of the call that is failing, not the one that is working for you through the API Explorer.  We can only tell what's wrong with the bad request not the good one.

Comment: The JSON request in my question now is the one that is formed by using `json_encode($body)`. So that is the incorrect JSON request.

Answer (score 1):

You are not hitting a valid DocuSign URL in your cURL code.  Right now you are sending requests to:

```
http://demo.docusign.net/apiVersion/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

Instead of "apiVersion" it should be "restApi" like this:

```
http://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the issue. The generic apiVersion string and the actual apiVersion string after it both have to be present. I'll mark this in my original question

Comment: You were correct about the url being off, but not because of a repeat scenario, but instead of `apiVersion` I should have `restapi`

Comment: When you are request a signing URL (i.e. recipient view) you need to reference the same exact recipient information that was used when you first added the recipient to the envelope.  Are you sure you are sending the same values, such as the `name`, `email`, and `clientUserId`?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

We can't send post fields, because we want to send JSON, not pretend to be a form (the merits of an API which accepts POST requests with data in form-format is an interesting debate). Instead, we create the correct JSON data, set that as the body of the POST request, and also set the headers correctly so that the server that receives this request will understand what we sent:

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
$ch = curl_init('http://api.local/rest/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

All these settings are pretty well explained on the [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) page, but basically the idea is to set the request to be a POST request, set the json-encoded data to be the body, and then set the correct headers to describe that post body. The CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is purely so that the response from the remote server gets placed in $result rather than echoed. If you're sending JSON data with PHP, I hope this might help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked more than 3 years ago, but this may help someone who finds this question because they are having the same problem. I do not see a cURL option that will decode the response in your code. I have found that I need to use the cURL option `CURLOPT_ENCODING` like this: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");` According to the PHP manual online, it says, 'CURLOPT_ENCODING - The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.' You can find this option at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. I hope this helps save someone from having a headache.